# AngularJS: Two-way data binding not finding model in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

- I am writing a `directive` which could be used at multiple places.
- The only requirement is that Controller using the directives will have their own model `budgetCategories`.

My `Controller` looks like

```
function BudgetController($scope, Budget, Category) {
        $scope.budgetCategories = [];
}
```

and `Directive` looks like

```
angular.module('categoryListingDirective', []).directive('categoryListing', function (Category) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: true,
        scope: {
            budgetCategories: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '../static/partials/categoryListingForm.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.recurring = true;
            scope.allParentCategories = undefined;
            scope.categories = Category.query(function () {
                scope.allParentCategories = _.uniq(scope.categories, function (category) {
                    return  category.parent;
                });
                console.log('all parent categories:', scope.allParentCategories);
            });

            scope.subCategories = function (parentCategoryName) {
                return _.filter(scope.categories, function (category) {
                    return category.parent == parentCategoryName;
                });
            };

            scope.addBudgetCategory = function () {
                console.log('adding budgetCategory:', scope.amount);
                scope.budgetCategories.push({
                    'amount': scope.amount,
                    'category': scope.subCategory ? scope.subCategory.name : '',
                    'parent_category': scope.parentCategory.parent,
                    'recurring': scope.recurring
                });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I want to make sure that `budgetCategories` from `Controller` is used by directive.

When I do this I get error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Scope.scope.addBudgetCategory (http://localhost:5000/static/app/js/directives/categoryListing.js:28:39)
    at http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10672:29
    at http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:18763:37
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:12533:44)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:12631:41)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:18762:39)
    at HTMLButtonElement.x.event.dispatch (http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/others/jquery-2.0.0.min.js:1321:108)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/others/jquery-2.0.0.min.js:1255:106)
```

**Question**

- What am I missing here?
- How can I make sure `budgetCatgories` from `Controller` is used by my `Directive`

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The `html` looks like

```
<div class="budgetEdit" category-listing="budget">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the html for the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line...

```
scope: {
    budgetCategories: '='
},
```

Creates an isolate scope for the directive, so its scope does not inherit from the parent scope and therefore has no access to `budgetCategories`. You have a few options...

1) Don't create an isolate scope by removing the `scope: { ... }` line from the directive definition.

2 ) Pass `budgetCategories` into the directive...

```
<div class="budgetEdit" category-listing="budget" budget-categories="budgetCategories"></div>
```

3) Use `$parent` to access the parent scope...

```
scope.$parent.budgetCategories.push({
    'amount': scope.amount,
    'category': scope.subCategory ? scope.subCategory.name : '',
    'parent_category': scope.parentCategory.parent,
    'recurring': scope.recurring
});
```

Comment: #1 works, I am so stupid that I did not realize that I am creating isolated scope :(. Thanks a lot @Anthony